# change the type of column in postgres not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column of type object, and i need to make it from another object type, (the table is empty )

i tried to do :

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_history ALTER COLUMN invoice_info TYPE invoice USING (trim(invoice_info)::invoice);
```

> ERROR:  function pg_catalog.btrim(invoice_item) does not exist LINE 1:
> ...ory ALTER COLUMN invoice_info TYPE invoice USING (trim(invoi...
> ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
> to add explicit type casts.

and :

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_history 
    ALTER COLUMN invoice_info TYPE invoice USING (invoice_info::invoice)
```

given this error  :

> ERROR:  cannot cast type invoice_item to invoice LINE 2: ...UMN
> invoice_info TYPE invoice USING (invoice_info::invoice...

what i should do ? and how can it changed  ?

Comment: If table is empty then drop one column and add another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table is empty (or you do not care about the column value conversion) use just `null`, e.g.:

```sql
alter table invoice_history 
    alter invoice_info type invoice using null;
```